# Mean and variance of ranks

Tags: self-study, econometrics, density-function, ranks

Consider rank data 1 to n with two groups, n=n1+n2, how would one test the null that the two groups have equal rank distributions using MOMENTS? (Wilcoxon is not the answer)

Is MLE possible to do the above?

If the ranks are for time periods, how does that affect the mean and variance.

Comment: How exactly will you rank ties? There are several conventions and the answer depends on which you choose.

Comment: To me the question is trying to look at ordinal and fractional ranking systems. Does this answer that?

Comment: This seems like routine bookwork, such as might be set as work or revision for some subject. Please add the `self-study` tag, and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), modifying your question as suggested there.

Comment: Surely you can identify the mean of the numbers $1,2,3,...,n$.

Comment: Of course, I can handle that. Ties would give the same mean if I'm thinking about that correctly. But the notation for variance considering ties is giving me issues.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Wilcoxon is not the answer"? The Wilcoxon test (using the usual adjustment for ties when mean ranks in tied groups are assigned to each group) is a perfectly valid test based on the first two moments of the ranks. When the asymptotic distribution is used to compute p-values, it is *identical* to a pooled-variance z-test.

Comment: I've edited to decrease the content of things that I already have to make my confusion more clear. Showing this by Wilcoxon is "not allowed" which is why I'm confused on this. So, considering 1 to n, is it now more of a uniform distribution and I can continue with the mean and variance from that distribution? All I know of MLE is that I "think" that the uniform distribution would be suitable. I am certainly clueless on how considering the ranks for time periods would change this.

Comment: Cross-posted at [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068565/mean-and-variance-of-rank-data-with-and-without-ties).

Comment: There's no need to consider uniform distributions. The ranks take known values; under the null (plus the assumptions) you're randomly sampling (without replacement) from those known values.

Answer (score 1):

The question could be clearer -- in particular, the way it's phrased, there are any number of things we could test for when assessing equality of rank distributions using moments - are we comparing the first moment, the first two moments, the first three, ... the first $n$ moments?

Let's just look at the first moment to start:

The ranks of $n$ items without ties are the numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$

Under the null, $n_1$ ranks are selected randomly from those $n$ to be the ranks of the first group and $n_2$ ranks are selected randomly to form the ranks of the second group.

So under the null the average rank in the first group will be $\frac{n+1}{2}$ and so will
the average rank in the second group.

If we take the difference in the average ranks in the sample we get a statistic that would be a reasonable test statistic for equality of rank distributions.

But that's an equivalent test to the using sum of ranks in say the first sample (they are linear transformations of each other with constant coefficients at given sample sizes). Which is to say, if you're comparing first moments, you *are* doing a Wilcoxon test.

Note that the variance of ranks is also not so hard. If you have a random selection of $n_1$ values (without replacement) from the set $1,2,...,n$, then the average squared rank in the first sample is fairly easy to work out, and similarly the variance of the mean rank in the first sample, and so on.

You could of course construct some statistic that looked at second moments, or first and second moments or some function of the first three moments and so on.

> If the ranks are for time periods, how does that affect the mean and variance.

It depends on what kind of dependence (if any) there is; it might make no difference; it might affect the variance depending on the particular kind of dependence.